# Algolia passing search state between different components

Tags: react-router, algolia

Im trying to get algolia instantsearch for react router 4 to render results while the `<searchbox />` is in another component. In the header nav i have a normal input box and was thinking it might be possible to pass the search term as its being typed to the Algolia results page and to its search state.
would it be possible to do this with state or redux or are there better options for this, atm they all seem to be quite excessive and im wondering if there are any better solutions for this.

EDIT: ive connected the input of the search component to redux with redux forms and its now stored there as form -> search: 'search': 'typed in to searchbox'
Algolia file is the same as below and i need to send the value of the search into the searchState but am unsure how to do this.

Algolia Results Component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  InstantSearch,
  Hits,
  Menu,
  Pagination,
  Configure,
  ClearAll,
} from 'react-instantsearch/dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import qs from 'qs';

const updateAfter = 700;

const createURL = state => `?${qs.stringify(state)}`;

const searchStateToUrl = (props, searchState) =>
  searchState ? `${props.location.pathname}${createURL(searchState)}` : '';

class Algolia extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchState: qs.parse(props.location.search.slice(1)) };
  }

  onSearchStateChange = searchState => {
    clearTimeout(this.debouncedSetState);
    this.debouncedSetState = setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.props.history.push(
          searchStateToUrl(this.props, searchState),
          searchState
        );
      },
      updateAfter
    );
    this.setState({ searchState });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <InstantSearch
        appId="someappid"
        apiKey="someapikey"
        indexName="someindexname"
        searchState={this.state.searchState}
        onSearchStateChange={this.onSearchStateChange.bind(this)}
        createURL={createURL}
      >
      <Configure hitsPerPage={20} />
        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={2}>
              <h4>Search By</h4>
              <Menu attributeName="type" />
              <ClearAll />
            </Col>

            <Col xs={10}>
              <Hits hitComponent={Products}/>
              <Pagination showLast={true} />
            </Col>
          </Row>

        </Grid>
      </InstantSearch>
    );
  }
}

function Products({hit}) {
  return (
    <Col md={4}>
         this.props.someinfo
    </Col>
    );
   }

Algolia.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }),
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default Algolia;
```

searchbox.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Searchbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { searchAlgolia: '' };
    this.setInputState = this.setInputState.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <InputGroup>
              <Field
                name="search"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Searc"
                value={this.state.term}
                onChange={event => this.setInputState(event.target.value)}
              />
              <div className="input-group-btn">
                <Button className="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></Button>
              </div>
            </InputGroup>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  setInputState(searchAlgolia) {
    this.setState({ searchAlgolia });
    // console.log('state from searchbox:', searchAlgolia);
  }
}

Searchbox = reduxForm({
  form: 'search'
})(Searchbox);

export default Searchbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you pass the `searchState` prop to `<InstantSearch>`, you could override the `query` property with the query you'd like it to start with, from wherever you're keeping it (in props or state).